# RcmdrMisc cannot be found

Tags: r

Looking to install RcmdrMisc in R any getting the below error message!

Thank you in advance!

> library(RcmdrMisc)
> Error in library(RcmdrMisc) : there is no package called ‘RcmdrMisc’
> Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib:
> cannot open URL 'https://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

Comment: The error says it cannot access the index for the repository. Try running `chooseCRANmirror()` and choosing a different repository. Are you explicitly setting the `repo=` when you call `install.packages()`? I can't access that repo link either. It looks like it redirected to the Microsoft MRAN which is no longer in service.

Comment: Us this instead. (That's an ancient and rotten link.) https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/RcmdrMisc_2.9-1.tar.gz